# Can't get textboxes in form-group to have the same width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my three basic form-groups to have the same length. I noticed that the width of the form-group di[image]v changes according to the length of the string of the .

As you can see, Password, having the the least number of characters has the shortest textbox while Confirm Password has the longest.

I've tried changing the grid size but it doesn't adjust and the form-group class has no width property.

```html
<div class="well row">
    <h3>Account Information</h3>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 spacer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Password</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides making a class to specify the width, what can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Password</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
```